# formatting used, but output is still not in a neat column

Tags: java, printf

I am writing code to get the information of bowling scores and print it into a neattable. I am trying to get the average rating and average score to print in a neat column. Here is my code.[my input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6y5u.png) [my output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wPN7.png)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Topic_HW5 {
    
    
    
    public static String oneGameScore(int x){
        String scr = " ";
        if (0<=x&&x<50) 
        scr = "Horrible";
        if (50<=x&&x<=99) 
        scr = "Poor";
        if (100<=x&&x<=139) 
            scr = "Good";
        if (140<=x&&x<=199) 
            scr = "Very Good";
        if (200<=x&&x<=249) 
            scr = "Excellent";
        if (250<=x&&x<=300) 
            scr = "Pro";
        if(x<0)
            scr= "Illegal <0";
        if(300<x)
            scr="Illegal <300";
        return scr;
    }
    
public static int avg3Scores(int x, int y, int z) {
    int avg=(x+y+z)/3;
    return avg;
    
}

    public static boolean validGroup(int x,int y, int z, PrintWriter outputFile) {
        boolean validGroup=false;
        
        if(0<=x&&x<=300)
        if(0<=y&&y<=300)
        if (0<=z&&z<=300)
         validGroup=true;
        else
            validGroup=false;
        return validGroup;
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//create outputFile
        PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter("hw5out.txt");
        File myinputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\chroZ\\eclipse-workspace\\Topic3\\src\\hw5input.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myinputFile);
        int score1, score2, score3,avg,avgrtg;
        int t,f=0;
        boolean valid;
        String rtg,rtg2,rtg3,grpavg= " ";
        outputFile.printf("%50s","TABLE OF BOWLING SCORES");
        //outputFile.printf("\nScore 1\tScore 2\tScore 3\t Valid?\tRating1\tRating2\tRating3");
        outputFile.printf("\n%1s %7s %7s %7s %8s %8s %8s     %12s %14s", "\nScore 1", 
                "Score 2", "Score 3", "Valid?", "  Rating1","     Rating2", "Rating3", "Avg Score", "Avg Rating");
        //"\n%1s %7s %7s %7s %8s %8s %8s", "\nScore 1", "Score 2", "Score 3", "Valid?", "Rating1","Rating2", "Rating3"
        System.out.println("What was score 1? ");
        score1 = inputFile.nextInt();
        while(score1 != -1) {
            System.out.println("What was score 2? ");
            score2 = inputFile.nextInt();
            System.out.println("What was score 3? ");
            score3 = inputFile.nextInt();
            valid=validGroup(score1,score2,score3,outputFile);
            rtg=oneGameScore(score1);
            rtg2=oneGameScore(score2);
            rtg3=oneGameScore(score3);
            avg=avg3Scores(score1,score2,score3);
            avgrtg=avg3Scores(score1,score2,score3);
            grpavg=oneGameScore(avgrtg);
            outputFile.println("\n");
            outputFile.printf("%1d %7d %7d %9b     %-12s %-8s %-8s %12d %16s",
                    score1,score2,score3,valid,rtg,rtg2,rtg3,avg, grpavg);
            
            
            System.out.println("What was score 1? ");
            score1 = inputFile.nextInt();
        }
        outputFile.println("\nThe program is complete!");
        inputFile.close();
        outputFile.close();
        outputFile.flush();
    }
}
```

AS you can see, the last two columns are all out of wack. I tried using formatting instead of \t's and spaces to print them neatly, expecting them to print in a straight column. Instead, they seem to be getting pushed to the side by previous data.I was wondering why this happens and how I can fix it

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a small improvement to make in the while condition:

```
while(inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("What was score 1? ");
    score1 = inputFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What was score 2? ");
    score2 = inputFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What was score 3? ");
    score3 = inputFile.nextInt();
    ...
```

In this way you don't have to check at the end of each cycle for another integer or compare with -1.

For the format masks:

```
String headerFormatMask = "%1s %7s %7s %-6s %-12s %-12s %-12s %1s %10s";
String formatMask       = "%1s %7s %7s %10s %-12s %-12s %-12s %1s %16s";
outputFile.printf(headerFormatMask,
        "Score 1",
        "Score 2",
        "Score 3",
        "Valid?",
        "Rating1",
        "Rating2",
        "Rating3",
        "Avg Score",
        "Avg Rating");
...
while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
   ...
   outputFile.println("\n");
   outputFile.printf(formatMask,
           score1,
           score2,
           score3,
           valid,
           rtg,
           rtg2,
           rtg3,
           avg,
           grpavg);
```

Notice how the header format mask and the one for each row balance each other out.

In total, the code in the adapted main method is:

```
// todo change input / output files as necessary
PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter("output.txt");
File myinputFile = new File("input.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myinputFile);
int score1, score2, score3,avg,avgrtg;
int t,f=0;
boolean valid;
String rtg,rtg2,rtg3,grpavg= " ";
outputFile.printf("%50s","TABLE OF BOWLING SCORES");
outputFile.printf("\n");
String headerFormatMask = "%1s %7s %7s %-6s %-12s %-12s %-12s %1s %10s";
String formatMask       = "%1s %7s %7s %10s %-12s %-12s %-12s %1s %16s";
outputFile.printf(headerFormatMask,
        "Score 1",
        "Score 2",
        "Score 3",
        "Valid?",
        "Rating1",
        "Rating2",
        "Rating3",
        "Avg Score",
        "Avg Rating");
while(inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("What was score 1? ");
    score1 = inputFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What was score 2? ");
    score2 = inputFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What was score 3? ");
    score3 = inputFile.nextInt();
    valid=validGroup(score1,score2,score3,outputFile);
    rtg=oneGameScore(score1);
    rtg2=oneGameScore(score2);
    rtg3=oneGameScore(score3);
    avg=avg3Scores(score1,score2,score3);
    avgrtg=avg3Scores(score1,score2,score3);
    grpavg=oneGameScore(avgrtg);
    outputFile.println("\n");
    outputFile.printf(formatMask,
        score1,
        score2,
        score3,
        valid,
        rtg,
        rtg2,
        rtg3,
        avg,
        grpavg);
    }
    outputFile.println("\nThe program is complete!");
    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
    outputFile.flush();
}
```